# Button Not Working (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, button

I'm working on an app and please find the below my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var NameTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ExplainTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var PriceTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var FeaturesTextLabel: UILabel!

let Features = ["Features Include: Siri acts as a musicologist, Advanced searches..., Works with Apple Music, etc", " Feautres Include: Up to 18 Cores, Thunderbolt 3, 5k Display, etc",
    "Feautres Include: AR technology, I messages wont take up storage, A redesinged appstore, etc", "New Faces, Siri Face, Better Pairing Process"]

let Explain = ["Apple Smart Speaker", "Most Powerfull Mac", "The New OS", "Watch OS4"]

let Price = ["At $349", "At $4999", "Free", "Free"]

let Name =  ["Homepod", "iMac Pro", "iOS 11", "Watch OS4"]

@IBAction func MoreDidTap(sender: AnyObject) {

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random()) % 4

    let NewName = Name [randomNumber]
    let NewExplain = Explain [randomNumber]
    let NewPrice = Price [randomNumber]
    let NewFeatures = Features [randomNumber]

    NameTextLabel.text = NewName
    ExplainTextLabel.text = NewExplain
    PriceTextLabel.text = NewPrice
    FeaturesTextLabel.text = NewFeatures
}
```

}

When I run the application in the simulator and I had found that while clicking on the button then nothing will change. If anyone knows then please help me.

Comment: have you put a breakpoint in your code in `MoreDidTap`? Does it get called?

Comment: Label and button event binding properly or not check once?

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect the `IBAction` to the `UIButton` for `touchUpInside` event?

A button must be set for an event to be notified. We can define a target and a selector to get that event back. The target represents the object which handles the event and the selector represents the method which acts on the event.

You can do this either by connecting the `UIButton` (in Storyboard/Xib) and `IBAction` (in class) or by programatically, using a UIButton API - `addTarget(_:action:for:)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working good
        check this steps
        Step 1 :- check in your storyboard your button sent events(eg.Touchupinside) set or not?
        Step-2 :- put print in MoreDidTap function if its working and even not changeing any thing,
        Step-3 :- Check your all label referance Outlet is given properly from storyboard or not?